# Is there any severe changelog for iOS6?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

Is there any "severe" or "critical" changelog for iOS6? I believe Apple's official documentation on "What's new" is very poor for navigation(too large), since there is only "good" new stuff. But nobody ever said that `IBAction` for `touchUpInside` is now superior to `gestureRecognizer` or that `CLLocationManager` already runs on main thread.

These are things I came across and found them afterwards in the Apple documentation. Since it is too large, it is too much to read it and then remember it and then when writing code, be like "oh right, they changed this, it's on page 42...".

Is there ANY(even fan/developer/enthusiast) page/blog that shows the top painful changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to [What's new](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) there are [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/) and [API Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS60APIDiffs/), mentioned in [Developer Library Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS_DevLib_Release_Notes/index.html) :)