# How to properly check iOS version controlling (from iOS 7.0)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

We are developing a project with a lot of functionality and module (Call, Chat, Update Feed and so on). It's deployment target is 7.0 to latest. This project has been developing since 2013. So there was a lot of bugs and old code. Recently this project is completed and ready to release in App Store.

But now we are finding some difficulties while testing it by QA. iOS changes many things according to it's version. We are struggling to check these changes in different versions.

For an example from iOS 8.3 the `facebook sharing` will have to implemented by their own SDK. The old `SLComposeViewController` is no more good. So we have to take care of it from iOS 8.3.

I just wondering if somehow we can get the list of these iOS versions where apple make changes, it would be easier for us to check the project installing those certain iOS version in iPhone. I think this type of information could be find in their developer site. If so any kind of information would be much helpful for us.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069129/is-there-any-severe-changelog-for-ios6) couple years ago (not saying this is a duplicate!), and all I got then was - "read the documentation carefully". Unfortunately it still remains true even now, but you can get some tools to help you out.

For external libraries, I strongly recommend using either **CocoaPods** or **Carthage**. You can specify which versions you want to support and those tools do the job for you to check whether that library you want to include will be compatible with your deployment targets.

For your *own code*, you have to just write XCTests to verify the most crucial parts of your app or possibly the whole codebase (*testing ftw*) and stick with version checking. That will be slightly more zen in Swift 2.0 where you'll be able to do API checking as well with `#available(iOS 9.0) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is really what you're asking for, but here's a link to all of [Apple's iOS release notes and API diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Release%20Notes) on their developer portal. I believe it covers all major versions of the iOS SDK.

But speaking from personal experience, I would also say that the actual impact of minor iOS updates on the functionality of existing apps is usually negligible. I would focus your QA efforts on the major versions you support (7.X and 8.X in your case) and use the latest stable release versions there for testing, as those will be the versions the vast majority of your users will be using.

That said, I think it's also an excellent idea to at least briefly look into the actual distribution and adoption rates of iOS versions in your user base, and agree on sensible cut-off points. If you find, for example, that 87% of your users are running iOS 8.X, 12.5% iOS 7.1.X and only  0.5% iOS 7.0.X, you might conclude that providing explicit testing and/or support for 7.0.X users is not actually worth the effort.

There are many sites that provide you with general numbers about [iOS adoption rates](https://mixpanel.com/trends/#report/ios_8/from_date:-29,report_unit:day,to_date:0) to give you a rough idea.

Lastly, if you feel that you've covered the (user-wise) biggest 2-3 versions in your testing, I think it's fair to push for your initial release and trust in your bug handling/update process to take care of any problems that *may* pop up in the more exotic iOS versions still out there. But that's of course a conscious decision you have to make for yourself.